# preload package in memory without attaching it

Tags: r, cran

What would be a good way to pre-load a bunch of commonly used R packages in memory when I start an R process, but not actually attach them. Preferably in such a way that there are no side effects.

If I do something like:

```
getNamespace("XML");
```

The package is loaded and it shows up in `sessionInfo()`:

```
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] XML_3.6-2
```

Does this have any side effects? I specifically want to prevent any form of masking if I do this for a large number of packages. The only purpose of this is to speed up the process when the `library()` function is called, or when `mypackage::somefunction` is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have a direct side-effect on the search path or global environment (which I think is what you are worried about). However, it will load dependent packages and run `.onLoad` which can in theory have side-effects (it should not, but in theory bad package authors could mess with your environment).

Comment: Is there any way to preload packages in memory without importing them yet, or running .onLoad?

Comment: You're asking whether you can load a package without loading it -- obviously, no :)

Comment: Hmm I suppose. I would have guessed one could distinguish the physical loading into the memory and parsing/preprocessing of the functions from actual step of importing it into the session. But then again, I have little knowledge about the underlying mechanics of loading packages so I'll take your word for it that it's a silly question :-)

Comment: The package functions are not really parsed/preprocessed because pretty much all packages today use lazy loading so you're not saving anything on that front. So the main things that happen is the resolution of dependencies and population of the package environment and namespace with promises (that simply contain `lazyLoadDBfetch` calls). You can't create the namespace without running `.onLoad` and loading dependencies so you can't really do anything.